# IP2Location suggesting to use DECIMAL(39, 0) for IPs

Tags: postgresql, ip2location

I'd like to store ip2location database in a postgres database.

[Guide on ip2location website](https://blog.ip2location.com/knowledge-base/importing-ip2location-data-into-postgresql-and-querying-with-php-ipv6/) suggests to store IP addresses that specify the range (`ip_from` and `ip_to`) in columns of type `DECIMAL(39, 0)`.

I would have expected this to be of type `INET`.

Is there any advantage (e.g. in terms of speed, size, ...) to use `DECIMAL(39, 0)` instead of `INET`? Other than the ip2location database format contains IPs converted to integers already and one would have to convert that back to IP addresses obviously.

Comment: They probably come from a MySQL background and don't even know that there are database that support proper data types for IP addresses. I am storing those CSV files without problems in tables using `inet`. Or maybe PHP can not handle more advanced data types.

Comment: I would not discard that whoever wrote the article was binge-writing articles for all major DBMS and just copied the same information over and over. But both formats are much better than `VARCHAR`.

Comment: Makes sense! Do you if there is any public code to load the CSV/do the conversion from integer to inet?

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of using the `inet` data type are

- it takes up only 4 bytes to store an IPv4 address
- you can make use of [all the useful built-in functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-net.html) for IP addresses and CIDRs

There is no advantage in using `NUMERIC(39)`, except that it seems to be required by the software you want to use.

Comment: I think some-user knows that. They are (rightfully) questioning the usage of the `decimal` type in that blog post.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The question I saw was "Is there any advantage (e.g. in terms of speed, size, ...) to use DECIMAL(39, 0) instead of INET? "